# How to resize div alone with browser size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Couldn't find a right answer in the forum, so i opened this thread for answer. 
i wanna create sth like on the link , which 2 div (farmer and Agronomists)
can resize when you change the browser size .
    http://www.agworld.com.au/?gclid=CjwKEAjwka67BRCk6a7_h_7Pui8SJABcMkWR_wNbB2t8jGf8Hs2bD2dnCBAB-MPmM2xAwMcyNvyhQhoC6sTw_wcB

but my div is overlapping when i resize. like below 
[image]

My code

```
<!-- Offer Posts -->
    <div class="text_container offer-background">
        <div class="offer-posts ">
            <div class="col-md-12 reason">
                <div class="verticalLine">                </div>

                <h1>What we offer</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="text_container">
                <!-- / .row -->
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-pad">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Postgres Support</h3>
                            <p class="card-text module line-clamp">We provide full 24/7 technical support for production PostgreSQL systems for your peace of mind. Let Fujitsu's PostgreSQL experts resolve your database problems while you focus on what you do best....
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-explore text-left">explore</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-pad">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Services</h3>
                            <p class="card-text module line-clamp ">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-explore">explore</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-pad">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Trainning</h3>
                            <p class="card-text module line-clamp">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-explore">explore</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-pad">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Postgres Solutions</h3>
                            <p class="card-text module line-clamp">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-explore">explore</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / .  -->
        </div>
        <!-- / .container -->
    </div>
    <!-- / .offer posts -->
    <!--  --
```

CSS code

```
    /* ===== offer Posts ===== */
.offer-background {
    background-color: #f7f9f8;
}
.card {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    content: "";
    max-width: 314px;
    height: 467px;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
.card img {
    width: 100%;
}
.card-title {
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.card-block {
    padding: 5px;
}
.card-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.card-text p {
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-size: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: left!important
}
.right-pad {
    /*        padding-left: 10px;
*/
}
.module {
    width: 314px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.module p {
    margin: 0;
}
.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

/**/
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: add class to img "img-responsive"

Comment: @LaljiTadhani That would solve the images overlapping but not the text.

Comment: The code you have provided would not make the text overlap like in your screenshot. You must have other CSS effecting the layout that you haven't shown us. Example: http://www.bootply.com/yaAcj1PGtz What does your `.right-pad` class do?

Comment: i have check your code no overlapping text https://jsfiddle.net/aerms5dv/
other css effect your custom css

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLjXEG will this help ?

Comment: use bootstrap then in img class give - "img-responsive", in your div's give class col-sm-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this `width` & add this class for img `img-responsive`

```
.module {
    /* width: 314px; */ /*Remove this width*/
     margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aerms5dv/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own media query. that can be written in 3 ways. I hope it will help you.

**For minimum width 768px**

```
@media (min-width:768px){
//your css code for screen larger than 768px goes here;
}
```

**For maximum width 768px**

```
@media (max-width:768px){
//your css code for screen smaller than 768px goes here;
}
```

**For minimum width 500px to 600px**

```
@media screen (min-width:500px) & (max-width:600px;){
//your css code for screen larger than 500px & smaller than 600px goes here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update this for your card class :

```
.card {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    content: "";
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 467px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.module {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks . Module width is missing there .~ thanks for that .!!

Comment: could you please mark the answer if this answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The sample you given in your question is developed by using twitter bootstrap. You just include `bootstrap.css` in your code and also you missing one `<div class="row"></div>` before columns.

Updated [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/L6p3gaqf/)